# How do I learn how to use slf4j?

Tags: java, logging, slf4j

I asked a question earlier today about log4j and was told that it is now "legacy" and that I should use slf4j and logback. So now I will use that but I don't understand where to start? slf4j is a abstraction layer over other logging frameworks after what I read but I can't find anything other than really basic hello world logging tutorials? How do I configure slf4j and use it?

Comment: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/04/using-slf4j-with-logback-tutorial.html

Comment: But is that all there is? I also read now that Logback is the "reference implementation" for the SLF4J framework, does that mean I can read the Logback tutorials (which is extensive) and that would apply to SLF4J?

Comment: It seems to me that they are all 'legacy' and that everybody should use the `java.util.logging` package, warts and all.

Comment: also, consider this static wrapper around SLF4J: [jcabi-log](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-log/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Slf4j is the API and yes logback is probably the implementation that you want.
Just use the slf4j logger classes in your code and the add logback.jar and logback.xml to your classpath.
The logback homepage contains a lot of the information you need to get started.

Answer (score 3):

You will be using slf4j with log4j (or any other logging implementation). So if you use log4j with slf4j you will have to provide the configuration for log4j in the log4j.properties. So the advantage is if you want to later change to Logback, you just have to replace the binding jar file(for log4j it may be `slf4j-log4j12-1.6.6.jar`) with new binding jar and add the configuration for Logback. No change in code.

This [thread](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/108683/slf4j-vs-log4j-which-one-to-prefer) should help you.
SLF4J [Manual](http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html)

Comment: But I don't understand, if SLF4J has its own syntax that wraps e.g. logback or log4j, where do I find that?

Comment: You can refer the slf4j [api doc](http://www.slf4j.org/api/). From a developer perspective tt is pretty much similar to log4j just the class names are different.